# Could not find a valid Docker Environment

Tags: kotlin, quarkus, colima

I just download a new project from https://code.quarkus.io with Kotlin + Gradle + REST and tried to execute `./gradlew quarkusDev`  and encountered following error:

```
2023-04-18 17:05:57,007 INFO  [org.tes.doc.DockerMachineClientProviderStrategy] (build-44) docker-machine executable was not found on PATH ***(masked on purpose) ***
2023-04-18 17:05:57,024 ERROR [org.tes.doc.DockerClientProviderStrategy] (build-44) Could not find a valid Docker environment. Please check configuration. Attempted configurations were:
        UnixSocketClientProviderStrategy: failed with exception InvalidConfigurationException (Could not find unix domain socket). Root cause NoSuchFileException (/var/run/docker.sock)As no valid configuration was found, execution cannot continue.
See https://www.testcontainers.org/on_failure.html for more details.
     2023-04-18 17:05:57,282 INFO  [org.tes.uti.ImageNameSubstitutor] (build-44) Image name substitution will be performed by: DefaultImageNameSubstitutor (composite of 'ConfigurationFileImageNameSubstitutor' and 'PrefixingImageNameSubstitutor')
<====2023-04-18 17:05:57,288 INFO  [io.qua.dep.dev.IsolatedDevModeMain] (main) Attempting to start live reload endpoint to recover from previous Quarkus startup failure
<====2023-04-18 17:05:57,613 ERROR [io.qua.dep.dev.IsolatedDevModeMain] (main) Failed to start quarkus: java.lang.RuntimeException: io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: Build failed due to errors
        [error]: Build step io.quarkus.kafka.client.deployment.DevServicesKafkaProcessor#startKafkaDevService threw an exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Previous attempts to find a Docker environment failed. Will not retry. Please see logs and check configuration
        at io.quarkus.kafka.client.deployment.DevServicesKafkaProcessor.startKafkaDevService(DevServicesKafkaProcessor.java:105)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.ExtensionLoader$3.execute(ExtensionLoader.java:909)
        at io.quarkus.builder.BuildContext.run(BuildContext.java:281)
        at org.jboss.threads.ContextHandler$1.runWith(ContextHandler.java:18)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2449)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1478)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1623)
        at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:501)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Previous attempts to find a Docker environment failed. Will not retry. Please see logs and check configuration
        at org.testcontainers.dockerclient.DockerClientProviderStrategy.getFirstValidStrategy(DockerClientProviderStrategy.java:212)
        at org.testcontainers.DockerClientFactory.getOrInitializeStrategy(DockerClientFactory.java:150)
        at org.testcontainers.DockerClientFactory.client(DockerClientFactory.java:186)
        at org.testcontainers.DockerClientFactory$1.getDockerClient(DockerClientFactory.java:104)
        at com.github.dockerjava.api.DockerClientDelegate.listContainersCmd(DockerClientDelegate.java:188)
        at io.quarkus.devservices.common.ContainerLocator.lookup(ContainerLocator.java:32)
        at io.quarkus.devservices.common.ContainerLocator.locateContainer(ContainerLocator.java:45)
        at io.quarkus.kafka.client.deployment.DevServicesKafkaProcessor.startKafka(DevServicesKafkaProcessor.java:222)
        at io.quarkus.kafka.client.deployment.DevServicesKafkaProcessor.startKafkaDevService(DevServicesKafkaProcessor.java:95)
        ... 9 more
```

My setup:

```
quarkus --version                                                                                                                                                                                                0|1 ↵  6451  17:15:31
2.16.6.Final


gradle --version                                                                                                                                                                                                    

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 8.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2023-04-12 12:07:45 UTC
Revision:     40ba32cde9d6daf2b92c39376d2758909dd6b813

Kotlin:       1.8.10
Groovy:       3.0.15
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.11 compiled on July 10 2021
JVM:          20 (Homebrew 20)
OS:           Mac OS X 11.6.2 x86_64
-------------------------------------------------
colima version    
                                                                                                                                                                                                  
colima version 0.5.4
git commit: feef4176f56a7dea487d43689317a9d7fe9de27e

runtime: docker
arch: x86_64
client: v20.10.22
server: v20.10.20
```

I haven't added any code apart from the skeleton provided by the builder and as stated above I am using colima instead of docker.

Comment: As you use Colima with Docker runtime you should be able to use it no problem. Is Colima properly started ?

Comment: yes colima started successully 

``` colima status                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
INFO[0000] colima is running using QEMU
INFO[0000] arch: x86_64
INFO[0000] runtime: docker
INFO[0000] mountType: sshfs
INFO[0000] socket: unix:///Users/**/.colima/default/docker.sock ```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your logs, you can see that Quarkus is trying to find docker socket in `/var/run/docker.sock`

But when using Colima, path is different :

> v0.3.4 or older ->
> Docker socket is located at $HOME/.colima/docker.sock
>
> v0.4.0 or newer ->
> Docker socket is located at $HOME/.colima/default/docker.sock
>
> It can also be retrieved by checking status with
> `colima status`

As you are currently using Colima v0.5.4, I suppose Quarkus should look to path `$HOME/.colima/default/docker.sock`. But to be extra confident, simply run `colima status` to get the actual one.

#### Properly configure env so Quarkus can find Docker .sock

You'll have to indicate it by running this command :

```bash
export DOCKER_HOST="unix://${HOME}/.colima/default/docker.sock"
```

#### OR Disable devServices

You can disable devServices, thus quarkus won't need docker to start anymore :
Simply add this `quarkus.devservices.enabled=false` in your `application.properties`

Comment: Feel free to accept answer if it met your expectations, thanks !

Answer (score -1):

This error tells you that during the build a Docket process is expected to be running on your machine. For example, Tescontainers library uses Docker to start processes (e.g. a database) that the application depends on for testing. To resolve the issue, download and install docker version which is suitable for your operating system. You can find instructions how to to do it on the Docker website: https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/

Comment: As OP's log state, docker runtime is present, check https://github.com/abiosoft/colima for more infos